# Find depth of a specific node in BST in C

Tags: c

Assume the following tree in preorder: 2, 9, 4, 7. I need to find depth of each node: node 2 - depth 0, node 9 - depth 1, node 4 - depth 2, node 7 - depth 3.

```
2
 \
  9
 /
4
 \
  7
```

However, the output I get is: node 2 - depth 0, node 9 - depth -1, node 4 - depth -1, node 7 - depth -1.

I think I'm not able to traverse right subtree because left becomes more than zero every time and function exits before reaching the right. But I'm not sure how can I fix the code to produce correct output.

My code:

```
int findDepth(Tree t, int key, int depth) {

    if (t == NULL) {
        return -1; 
    }

    if (t->value == key) {
        return depth;
    }

    int left = findDepth(t->left, key, depth + 1);
    if (left != 0) {
        return left; 
    }

    int right = findDepth(t->right, key, depth + 1); 
    if (right != 0) {
        return right; 
    }

    return 0; 

}

int treeNodeDepth(Tree t, int key) {

    return findDepth(t, key, 0);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call `int left = findDepth(t->left, key, depth + 1);` both when there is and when there is no node. Both could be ok but if you call with `NULL` you should update the test

```
   if (left != 0) {
        return left; 
    }
```

so you do not return when `-1` is received from sub-tree.

Option one, test before calling:

```
if (t->left){
    int left = findDepth(t->left, key, depth + 1);
    if (left != 0) {
        return left; 
    }
}
```

option two change the test:

```
int left = findDepth(t->left, key, depth + 1);
if (left > 0) {
    return left; 
}
```

A third option would be to change the return value on Nullpointers, to match the test above.

```
if (t == NULL) {
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is here

```
 int left = findDepth(t->left, key, depth + 1);
if (left != 0) {
    return left; 
}
```

lets say you search for 9, but when you come to root (ie 2) it will check left because of the above code and return -1 because left of 2is null and you are returning -1 for null. Since -1 is not equal to 0 This code will return -1 instead of the correct position of 9.
There are multiple fixes to this but I will leave that to you. If you still cant figure how to fix it leave a comment, I will provide some options